# Assigning proper modifiers correctly in C# when it comes to abstract classes

Tags: c#, abstract, access-modifiers

I have run into this situation many times, and have 'hacked' my way around the situation, but it seems it's a gap in my understanding.

Given the following code:

```
public class Foo
{
    Bar barA = new BarA();

    private void Bat() => barA.Baz();
}

public abstract class Bar
{
    // Obviously this *can't* be private
    private abstract Baz();
}

public class BarA : Bar
{
    public void Run() => Baz();

    // Again this can't be private 
    private override Baz() => DoSomething();
}
```

(caveat: I used expression bodied methods for sake of brevity in the example.  Normally I would not unless there was a good reason to.)

Now, in the above example, my logic is that the `Baz` method needs to be defined by the concrete class, however the reason I want it private (and yes, I understand WHY it can't be, because it would be completely invisible/inaccessible to the concrete class), is logically, I do not want the concrete class to be able to call the method, merely define it.

The way to fix the code is to make the method `protected`, however, then the method becomes available to executable from within the concrete class.

Ultimately, I want an abstract/base class that handles internals of executing some code that is defined by the concrete class, however never available for the concrete class itself to call/execute.  What is the flaw with that logic, or how should I be implementing that logic properly.

** EDIT: A concrete implementation **

Let's say for example this is part of a plugin system within a library (that I am creating, and another developer is implementing).  Another part of the library uses derived classes that implement this abstract class (say it's a filter in image processing).  The developer define's the method on what the filter does, however the abstract class (essentially handles the only processing that the defined filter provides), and yes the contract (interface) is made for the image processor so it doesn't (need to) know/care about implementation anyhow.

Comment: I really don't understand why you care about the `Baz` method at all. If it's a private implementation of the base class then the derived class shouldn't ever care about it.

Comment: @DavidG what I am saying is that the derived class needs to define it but the base class should only ever call it.

Comment: I think there's a code smell here. If the base class requires something to be defined by the derived class, then either make it public or pass in an object to the base class constructor that does the work.

Comment: @DavidG Agreed, make it public or maybe create an Interface. Passing an object from derived to base class kinda smells tho

Comment: Why would the concrete class call the method?

Comment: Let me get this straight.  The concrete class cannot call the method it it supplies?   That is going to make for some interesting Debug and unit testing.

Comment: As I noted though, if I make it protected, then it's accessible to the derived class, making it public would make it available to everyone which is worse yet.  As for what DavidG is saying, that makes some sense to pass it to the base constructor then I can keep it private (inaccessible to the derived class beyond definition), Going to see how that looks now.

Comment: So you don't want BarA to be able to call this.Baz()?  If calling Baz is detrimental to BarA then why would BarA call it?  It is hard to protect yourself from yourself.

Comment: Here's a concrete example: [Implementing the dispose pattern for a derived class](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/implementing-dispose#implementing-the-dispose-pattern-for-a-derived-class).    The derived class overrides `protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)` but should never call it directly.  Instead `Dispose()` in the base class should be called (or the class should be used in a `using` statement.)  More generally one can imagine situations where a base method does some setup & cleanup, and calls the virtual method for intermediate work.

Comment: @paparazzo I see your point there, I have to think about that.

Comment: @iamjp well calling Baz isn't necessarily detrimental, it's more a matter of least access, the code within BarA should never *need* to access it, merely define it for the abstract class to use (again this is my logic and I am trying to understand the fault in my logic more than how to fix the code)

Comment: The dispose pattern is a good example.  Unfortunately, the language lacks any Access Modifier that would only allow access from a base class.

Comment: @AaronMurray problem in your logic is you want to prevent some class, which code you even not necessary own (inherited class) to call its own method. If you wanted to prevent calling _base_ method - you would just declare it private, but you want to prevent calling own class method.

Comment: @dbc that seems not quite relevant. It's perfectly fine for derived class to call `this.Dispose()`, and OP wants to prevent exactly that (as I understand).

Comment: @Evk yes (if I am understanding  you correctly), but let's reverse this, let's say this is part of a library I created, where another developer implements the abstract class.  In this case, another developer defines the derived class (set's the rules / parameters, but doesn't determine how the abstract class handles the processing)

Comment: You should worry about protecting your classes from unnecessary access.  You can't prevent another developer from breaking their own code.  In the example, just use 'protected'

Comment: *Let's say for example this is part of a plugin system within a library.* -- to what extent can you modify the designs for the base class and derived classes?

Comment: @dbc meaning I am creating the library and another developer is using the library.  I see the ambiguity of that example.

Comment: Even if it worked if they have the code they can copy past and make a public MyBaz.   It is like trying to secure code by hiding a password inside.

Comment: @paparazzo yeah and if they had a decompiler and the library dll they could get the code, I think you are going beyond the logistics now.  The whole point of the question was to determine the flaw in logic, not the million ways someone could counteract it, it's not about security, it's about how to write the code itself properly.  I am trying to 'hide' the code within the abstract class not for the purpose of hiding it but for the purpose of not exposing it to the rest of the code.  It really has nothing to do with the security of what's inside to the developer.

Comment: How is stopping them from running a method not about security.  Sorry I tried to help.

Comment: It's more like the base class says `This is exactly how I am going to do it, just give me the method I need to execute in order to do it, but don't bother calling the method because you will call this method instead and use the results I provide`, and no need for apologies, I am just trying to prevent going too far out of scope for the logistics of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like I said in the comments, what you're trying to do is a bit of a code smell. If your derived class needs to define how something in the base class works, then consider passing in an interface to the base. That way you're note exposing any public methods you don't need to and making things much more testable. You could do it something like this.

The interface and an implementation:

```
public interface IBaz
{
    void Baz();
}

public class BigBaz : IBaz
{
    public void Baz() => Console.WriteLine("Big Baz!");
}
```

Now your code slightly modified:

```
public abstract class Bar
{
    private readonly IBaz _baz;
    public Bar(IBaz baz)
    {
        _baz = baz;
    }

    public void DoBaz() => _baz.Baz();
}

public class BarA : Bar
{
    //Here I'm passing into the constructor, but you may find it preferable
    //to pass the IBaz directly as a parameter of the DoBaz method
    public BarA() : base(new BigBaz())
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: I like the answer but nothing is stopping BarA from new BigBax for them-self.

Comment: @paparazzo And what is the problem with that? The point is that `Bar` doesn't have the implementation.

Comment: This whole thing is confusing to me.

Comment: @paparazzo I think that's only because the question is making some odd assumptions. This code here is pretty simple.

Comment: I think this does answer my question, and I really do see the code smell you are referring to which clarifies the underlying logic to my problem in the first place.  I am in the process of going back through my own code/implementation to revise the code smell and create a cleaner approach to the problem at hand.

Comment: @paparazzo it's much easier to understand both the question and answer if you look at it more from a perspective of flaw in logic (mine) vs trying to implement the sample code.  Through all the great comments as well as the solution, I think there is some real clarification to the problems with the underlying logic.